# How to import the tensorflow go packages when using go modules in a project?

Tags: tensorflow, go

So I have a project and I am using go modules. However I need to use the tensorflow package, but it seems tensorflow is not yet supporting go modules. Is there a way to import those two dependencies despite the lack of module definitions?

The following 2 imports seem to cause the problems:

```
tf "github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go"
"github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/op"
```

When I try to download the packages I get the following output:

```
$ go get -u "github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/op"
go: finding github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/op latest
go: finding github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go latest
go: finding github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow latest
go get github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/op: no matching versions for query "latest"
```

However in my test project which still used the old way of importing packages everything worked just fine.

Edit:

After some testing I realized that the issue only happens with the go packages of tensorflow. All others, even if not originally written with go modules, work just fine.

I corrected the imports in the original question, as well as the title.

Comment: What was the value of the `GO111MODULE` environment variable when you entered the command, and what was your working directory?

Comment: So my `GO111MODULE` variable seems to be not set.

At first I had the project located inside `$GOPATH/src` and later moved it out to the home directory.

And I also upgraded go to 1.12.7, but without success.

Comment: Is it possible that the issue is caused by the unusual* repo structure of tensorflow where the go project is not at the root of the repository?

*with unusual I mean unusual for go projects

Answer (score 0):

So for now I use a dirty workaround to get around this issue. I just ripped out go modules from my project entirely by removing `go.mod` and `go.sum` files and setting `GO111MODULE=off`.

It is not the best solution, hence I do not accept the answer, but for now I can continue working.